# How do i make a try loop work for txt file loading?

Tags: python

I have created a code to lead a txt file as an csv, however, when i ask the user to input doc. number, my try loop will not check the doc. Instead it is stuck asking for the file name. If i remove the first if-function (if choice=="") it works, however, I need that if-functions later on.
The code is as following

```
def menu2(choice1):
while True:
    if choice1=="":
        choice1=float(input("""\033[1;36;48mNow you have the following choices:
                          0: Set new directory
                          1: Load data
                          5: Quit
                          
                \033[1;37;48mPlease enter a number: """))
        print()
    elif choice1 == 0:
        menu1()
    elif choice1 == 1:
        print("\033[1;36;48mTo load the data, the data document name needs to be given with "".txt"" at the end")
        choice2=input("""
                \033[1;37;48mPlease enter the name of the document: """)
        print()
        try:
             pd.read_csv(choice2, sep=" ", header=None)
        except:
             print("Error, could not find data in directory. Files in directory is listed below:")
             print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
             continue
        menu3("")
    elif choice1 == 5:
        print("Thanks for using the data analysis program, bye")
        break
    else:
        print(red+"Not a valid option, please try again"+white)
        print()
        continue
prevData=pd.read_csv(choice2, sep=" ", header=None)
return prevData
```

Comment: "try loop"? `try` doesn't start a loop.

Comment: I think you would do well to check out a few basic tutorials on Python. You're clearly on top of the `if .. elif .. else` structure, but it's not a golden hammer and not everything is a nail. Try stepping through the code line by line, keeping track of the values of your various variables and figure out why the code does what it does and how you want that flow to change. If there's some specific part you don't get, ask about that - a broad "why doesn't my program work" isn't a very good question, in that you're not likely to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

make a variable `loop = True` and change your `while True` to `while loop`. Inside the try statement, after reading the csv, you can make `loop = False` and it will break the loop.